# psutils, how to correctly calculate a process CPU utilization

Tags: python, psutil

I have the following process:

```
PID = 1245
p   = psutil.Process(PID)
```

When I calculate the `cpu` utilization of this process:

```
print(p.cpu_percent())
```

it gives something like `25%`. While the whole CPU utilization is about `3%`:

```
print(psutil.cpu_pecent())
```

How come? How can I get a representative percentage of this particular process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely due to the 3% being total usage over all cores while 25% is usage of a single core capacity. You can always look at the documentation of [`psutil.cpu_percent()`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_percent) and [`psutil.Process.cpu_percent()`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_percent) to get some more in-depth explanation of the behaviour.

To get the usage of total system capacity you need to divide it by the number of CPUs you got access to:

```py
PID = 1245
p   = psutil.Process(PID)
tot_load_from_process = p.cpu_percent()/psutil.cpu_count()
print(tot_load_from_process)
print(psutil.cpu_pecent())
```

Comment: How can I calculate this percentage out of all cores. is `usage=.03/.25` is the solution ? or how can I get a representative percentage of this particular process ?

Comment: I updated the answer with some code, hopefully it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I still see some differences when compared with the cpu usage from `task manager`

Comment: Is the CPU usage constant? Otherwise measuring at different times will yield different results (at the risk of being obvious).